# How do I adapt my recommendation engine to cold starts?

Tags: prediction, recommendation-engine, cold-start

I am curious what are the methods / approaches to overcome the "cold start" problem where when a new user or an item enters the system, due to lack of info about this new entity, making recommendation is a problem.

I can think of doing some prediction based recommendation (like gender, nationality and so on).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe there are times you just shouldn't make a recommendation?  "Insufficient data" should qualify as one of those times.

I just don't see how prediction recommendations based on "gender, nationality and so on" will amount to more than stereotyping.

IIRC, places such as Amazon built up their databases for a while before rolling out recommendations.  It's not the kind of thing you want to get wrong; there are lots of stories out there about inappropriate recommendations based on insufficient data.

Answer (score 23):

You can cold start a recommendation system.

There are two type of recommendation systems; collaborative filtering and content-based.  Content based systems use meta data about the things you are recommending.  The question is then what meta data is important?  The second approach is collaborative filtering which doesn't care about the meta data, it just uses what people did or said about an item to make a recommendation.   With collaborative filtering you don't have to worry about what terms in the meta data are important.   In fact you don't need any meta data to make the recommendation.  The problem with collaborative filtering is that you need data.  Before you have enough data you can use content-based recommendations.  You can provide recommendations that are based on both methods, and at the beginning have 100% content-based, then as you get more data start to mix in collaborative filtering based. 
That is the method I have used in the past.

Another common technique is to treat the content-based portion as a simple search problem.   You just put in meta data as the text or body of your document then index your documents.  You can do this with Lucene & Solr without writing any code.

If you want to know how basic collaborative filtering works, check out Chapter 2 of "Programming Collective Intelligence" by Toby Segaran

Comment: This is the best answer and really deserves the check mark.  I would add that bandit algorithms could have a role in discovering baseline rates for new products or determining the tradeoff between content based and collaborative approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Working on this problem myself, but this paper from microsoft on Boltzmann machines looks worthwhile: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/81783/gunawardana09__unified_approac_build_hybrid_recom_system.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked several times before (naturally, I cannot find those questions now :/, but the general conclusion was it's better to avoid such recommendations. In various parts of the worls same names belong to different sexes, and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations based on "similar users liked..." clearly must wait. You can give out coupons or other incentives to survey respondents if you are absolutely committed to doing predictions based on user similarity.

There are two other ways to cold-start a recommendation engine.

1. Build a model yourself.
2. Get your suppliers to fill in key information to a skeleton model. (Also may require $ incentives.)

Lots of potential pitfalls in all of these, which are too common sense to mention.

As you might expect, there is no free lunch here. But think about it this way: recommendation engines are not a business plan. They merely enhance the business plan.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things needed to address the Cold-Start Problem:

1. The data must have been profiled such that you have many different features (with product data the term used for 'feature' is often 'classification facets'). If you don't properly profile data as it comes in the door, your recommendation engine will stay 'cold' as it has nothing with which to classify recommendations.
2. MOST IMPORTANT: You need a user-feedback loop with which users can review the recommendations the personalization engine's suggestions. For example, Yes/No button for 'Was This Suggestion Helpful?' should queue a review of participants in one training dataset (i.e. the 'Recommend' training dataset) to another training dataset (i.e. DO NOT Recommend training dataset).
3. The model used for (Recommend/DO NOT Recommend) suggestions should never be considered to be a one-size-fits-all recommendation.  In addition to classifying the product or service to suggest to a customer, how the firm classifies each specific customer matters too.  If functioning properly, one should expect that customers with different features will get different suggestions for (Recommend/DO NOT Recommend) in a given situation.  That would the 'personalization' part of personalization engines.